# What are the psychological effects for Munchausen by Proxy (MSBP) victims? Stockholm-Syndrome?

Tags: emotional-abuse, physical-abuse, munchausen-syndrome, stockholm-syndrome

I was listening to the hit true-crime podcast, "My Favorite Murder," (don't judge it by it's name until you listen to it -- it's not what you think), and one of the cases they discussed was about Gypsy Rose Blanchard and her mother, Dee Dee (episode 47). You can read the details of the case [here](http://crimefeed.com/2017/05/munchausen-by-proxy/), but basically Gypsy Rose's mother had Munchausen by Proxy (MSBP), which means she feigned the illness of her child (by deliberately harming her) in order to receive attention, funds, etc. from the community. In Gypsy Rose's case, her mother made her sick and claimed she had leukemia and had to eat through a tube for more than a decade until finally Gypsy Rose was able to murder her abuser, her mother.

Anyway, my question is this: **Are victims of Munchausen by Proxy likely to violently react to their abuser or will they develop a codependepent relationship (akin to Stockholm syndrome)?** How common is Gypsy Rose's reaction to her abuser?

Comment: This would be a better fit in CogSci.SE

Comment: Interesting q but yes it's more likely to be answered by psychological professionals than medical professionals.

Comment: I tried googling for both terms and the only thing that came out was [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22805905), so my guess is that it's unlikely that the victim develops Stockholm syndrome, unless that is part of the scheme developed by the victimizer.